# Author data not being recognized in Google structured data testing tool

Tags: google-plus, author, structured-data

I've searched all over the place and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. No matter what I still get a `Page does not contain authorship markup` on the structured data testing tool

I have two sites with almost identical pages. The `rel=author` tags are inserted the same way.

Here is an example of one page that works: http://bit.ly/18odGef

Here is an example of one page that doesn't: http://bit.ly/12vXdAm

I tried adding `?rel=author` to the end of the Google+ profile URL, which doesn't seem to work on either site.  I am not blocking anything via `nofollow` or `robots.txt`. The tool is not being blocked by a firewall or anything. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here and why it works for one site, but not the other?

FYI, the site that does not work used to work without a problem. I hadn't changed anything with how the author markup was organized until I realized it wasn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When I test both of those pages in Google's structured data test tool, it shows that authorship is working correctly for both pages.

Here are the results for the page you said was working: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fnikonites.com%2Fd5100%2F2507-d5100-vs-d90.html%23axzz2rFFm1eVv

Here are the results for the page you said wasn't working: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcellphoneforums.net%2Fsamsung-galaxy%2Ft359099-enable-auto-correct-galaxy-note-ii.html%23axzz2rFFlwz3W

Comment: yes, for some reason it works now. Google changed something with the tool. I haven't changed anything in the way things are added.